# Git model for story branch with many feature branches

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

My team started a new story that will be delivered in ~ 2 weeks time. The story is broken down into multiple features that will be handled by several developers. The flow is the following:

```
(master) - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  S* - - >
   ↓                                          ↑                                            
(story) - - - - - A* - B* - - - - - - - C*- - -
   ↓              ↑    ↑    ↓           ↑
(feature A) - - - ↑    ↑    ↓           ↑
   ↓                   ↑    ↓           ↑
(feature B) - - - - - -↑    ↓           ↑
                         (feature C) - -
```

`Story` branch is taken from master. Developers branch from the story branch and create feature branches. `git rebase` is done frequently with `story` to minimise the number of conflicts. Once the feature is complete (`A*`, `B*`, `C*`), commits are squashed and the branch is merged into `story` with `--no-ff`.

`master` changes very frequently as it's getting commits from other teams.

Once every feature is complete `story` will be merged back to `master` (`S*`).

The challenge here is how to keep `story` in sync with `master`? I would like to use `git rebase master` twice per day to keep history clean but I'm aware commits will be changed and this might affect `feature` branches badly.

I would like to hear suggestions about a safe workflow (`git merge --no-commit`?) to accomplish this model.

Comment: Just so I get this right: While the team works on the story, there is still more development on master? What’s going on there? Also, where would you like to use `git rebase master` twice a day? On the story, or on the features; and why do you want this? If there is actual development on master, this will just introduce the need to resolve conflicts multiple times.

Comment: It's my experience that `story` often ends up acting more like `vignette`. That is, the only real way to avoid having `story` not conflict with `master` on `S*` is to merge back into master more frequently. I'd love to hear other options, though.

Comment: @jeremytwfortune Merging the story *into* master before its completion kind of defeats its purpose though.

Comment: @poke I absolutely agree. I just haven't seen a workflow where you can have a branch persist without eventually guaranteeing a conflict or rebasing commits on it (which makes current feature branches diverge).

Comment: @poke And if I can speak for @noisebleed, there are typically other stories on `master`. So those other persistent branches are getting merged into `master`. `hotfix` branches are also a primary culprit.

Comment: @poke Yes, master is being updated several times per day. Updated my question.

Comment: That's not a story. That is epic or theme. You broke it into stories.

Answer (score 4):

Rebasing **rewrites history**. [You should **never rewrite history of already-published commits**](https://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html#_rebase_peril) (especially if you know that further branches are based on them), or you'll make everything much more difficult for your coworkers than it should be.

The workflow you're suggesting should work fine with merging instead of rebasing. Regularly merging `master` into `story` and `story` into any still-active features branches for `story` will not avoid merge conflicts (rebasing wouldn't either, though), but will allow you to handle them in small, manageable chunks rather than in one big <del>bang</del> mess.

> I wan't to avoid `merge master into story` kind of commits when merging `story` into `master` at the end of the development.

Why? They're nothing to be ashamed of.

> What do you recommend? `git checkout story && git merge master --no-commit`?

What this will do is to merge `master` into `story` without implicitly committing. The merge will be in your working copy only until you manually commit, which allows you to manually modify the merge result before persisting it. When you then manually commit, the resulting commit will still be a merge commit, i.e. it will have two parents (unless you've removed the merge from the working copy e.g. with `git reset --hard HEAD` or `git checkout .`.)

> Also, do you see any issue with `git rebase story` for `feature` branches?

Simply apply [the rule](https://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html#_rebase_peril)

> **Do not rebase commits that exist outside your repository.**

This means, if feature branches aren't shared and thus each of them only exists in the local repository of the respective single developer working on them, rebasing won't cause any issues. (But it would have to be done by the respective developer, as he's the only one with the branch in their repo.)

If, however, feature branches are shared (pushed or pulled to other repositories), there's the risk that others have their own commits based on them, thus you should not rewrite them in that case.

Comment: I wan't to avoid `merge master into story` kind of commits when merging `story` into `master` at the end of the development. What do you recommend? `git checkout story && git merge master --no-commit`? Also, do you see any issue with `git rebase story` for `feature` branches?

Comment: I've replied to your comment in the answer above.

Comment: It is important to make a clear concious decision about what "Publish" means locally, before applying the 'never re-write history' rule. The power of Git is that control has been distributed down the 'command chain', so the developer is able to make these better decisions. In addition the repositories can be distributed. Pushing to one repository (with colleagues pulling from it) does not have to be 'publishing', while at the same time the same 'push' to a different repository could be publishing. The OP need to regain that control that should have been distributed...